# AutoSys - difference between "On No Execution" and "On Ice"

Tags: autosys

Here is a great explanation of the difference between [On Hold and On Ice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45760827/difference-between-on-ice-and-on-hold-jobs-in-autosys) in AutoSys.

Yet, I can't find something similar for On No Execution and On Ice.  Does anyone know what "On No Execution" brings to the table?

Answer (score 1):

An "ON ICE" job does not run at all (downstream dependencies are immediately triggered)

An "ON NO EXECUTION" job appears to have run to its downstream dependencies (which get a SUCCESS message from this job). Additionally, the start and end times of the job will update daily (if the job is scheduled to run daily) but the underlying command is never actually run

So in a nutshell these is no real difference, except that an "ON NO EXECUTION" job appears to be running daily (and completing immediately) if you query the autosys database

Answer (score 0):

ON_NOEXEC
Indicates that the scheduler bypasses execution of the job.

Notes:

- You can place a job in this status only by sending the JOB_ON_NOEXEC event.
- These jobs, and box jobs containing them, evaluate as successfully completed.
  Downstream jobs that are dependent on these jobs still run, conditions
  permitting.
- When you instruct the scheduler to bypass the execution of a box job, the
  scheduler automatically places all jobs in that box job in ON_NOEXEC status.
- To resume executing bypassed jobs, send the JOB_OFF_NOEXEC event.

Source:
[CA Workload Automation AE - User Guide - Release 11.3.6](https://ftpdocs.broadcom.com/cadocs/0/CA%20Workload%20Automation%20AE%20Release%2011%203%206%20-%20Public%20Access-ENU/Bookshelf_Files/PDF/WA_AE_User_ENU.pdf)